# Spring WebFlow. Pass value from button

Tags: spring-webflow

Is it possible in Spring WebFlow to pass the value of a button to the flow...?
Something like this:

```xml
<button name="_eventId_next" type="submit" id="BTN_START" value="1" />
```

and then try to get it into the flow like this:

```xml
<view-state id="information" view="information">
    <transition on="back" to="init" validate="false"/>
    <transition on="next" to="followPage">
        <set name="buttonValue" value="[button.value]" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

and use it in anothor JSP page?

Thanks to everyone could help me.

// Daniele.